# ReactJs Using refs for focusing an input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use refs is ReactJs, to focus the textbox from a button click.

But I get the following error message:-

```
bundle.js:114 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined
```

Source Code

```
class FocusText extends Component{

        handleClick(){
            this.refs.myTextInput.focus();
        }

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <input type="text" ref="myTextInput"/>
                    <input type="button"
                           value="Focus the text input"
                           onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    React.render(<FocusText/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760815/react-vs-react-dom-confusion/39761242#39761242

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the others have said, string refs have been deprecated.

However it still works right now with the string ref, but in the last line I would  use `ReactDOM`

```
ReactDOM.render(<FocusText />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

In your code you aren't using ReactDOM. Is there are reason for that?

**See the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/NgmRMR?editors=0010)**

Comment: I'm following a textbook, it never states to reference it, if you hadn't questioned this id have been stuck for eternity! Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! :) I'm glad it worked

Answer (score 3):

[String refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element) are deprecated, and according to the docs...

> We advise against it because string refs have some issues, are
>   considered legacy, and are likely to be removed in one of the future
>   releases.

You should use the [callback ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element) instead.

Assign the ref to a property on the instance:

```
<input type="text" ref={(input) => { this.myTextInput= input; }} />
```

Use the ref:

```
handleClick(){
    this.myTextInput.focus(); // note that refs is no longer necessary 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a callback:

```
class FocusText extends React.Component{

        handleClick(){
            console.log(this.focus)
        }

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <input type="text" ref={ focus => this.focus = focus }/>
                    <input type="button"
                           value="Focus the text input"
                           onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    React.render(<FocusText/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

From React documentation:

> If you worked with React before, you might be familiar with an older API where the ref attribute is a string, like "textInput", and the DOM node is accessed as this.refs.textInput. We advise against it because string refs have some issues, are considered legacy, and are likely to be removed in one of the future releases. If you're currently using this.refs.textInput to access refs, we recommend the callback pattern instead.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: It was failing because i was using React.render rather than using the ReactDOM.render from 'react-dom'. :-(