# react render doesn't show anything

Tags: reactjs, codepen

My react codepen is not showing anything.

JS

```
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div>Hello World!</div>);
    }
}
var app = document.getElementById("mainapp");
React.render(<HelloWorld />, app);
```

HTML

```
<div id='mainapp'></div>
```

I imported React and ReactDOM trough a cdn. And if I type React/ReactDOM in the console it is imported correctly. This code doesn't show any errors yet I see nothing. I tested this on multiple browsers (chrome, firefox, icecat) but still no results... I'm using bable is a preprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReactDOM.render` not `React.render`.

```js
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>Hello World!</div>;
    }
}
var app = document.getElementById("mainapp");
ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloWorld/>,
  app
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='mainapp'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component needs to return an element instead of a naked string. Try to modify it to `<div>Hello World!</div>`

Comment: I've tried all combinations of strings, html and jsx but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Two things

1. You need to return a valid react element
2. Use `ReactDOM.render` instead of `React.render`

Snippet

```js
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>"Hello World!"</div>
    }
}
var app = document.getElementById("mainapp");
ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, app);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="mainapp"></div>
```

Also see this answer on why you should use ReactDOM

[react vs react DOM confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760815/react-vs-react-dom-confusion/39761242#39761242)